# How to make figure and listing share their counter

Tags: floats, numbering, listings, counters

I'm using the "listings" package to write pieces of code (XML, RDF, Java, etc) and I want them to have the same counter of the Figure environment.

For example,

```
Listing 1: blablabla
Listing 2: blebleble
Figure 3: bliblibli
Listing 4: blobloblo
Figure 5: blublublu
```

The purpose of doing it is to change the "Listing" label to "Figure". But I need both environments to share the same counter. How I do it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can make things so the `figure` environment shares the counter with `lstlisting`. However, you should ensure that `lstlisting` environments are floating too, otherwise the numbers could not agree and a figure could appear before a listing with a lower number.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}

\makeatletter
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \let\c@figure\c@lstlisting
  \let\thefigure\thelstlisting
  \let\ftype@lstlisting\ftype@figure % give the floats the same precedence
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}[caption=A listing,float]
a=1
\end{lstlisting}

\begin{lstlisting}[caption=Another,float]
b=2
\end{lstlisting}

\begin{figure}
F
\caption{A figure}
\end{figure}

\begin{lstlisting}[caption=Again,float]
c=3
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Thanks to David Carlisle for noting the need for adjusting `\ftype@lstlisting`.

If you also want that `table` shares the counter, add similar instructions.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}

\makeatletter
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \let\c@figure\c@lstlisting
  \let\thefigure\thelstlisting
  \let\c@table\c@lstlisting
  \let\thetable\thelstlisting
  \let\ftype@lstlisting\ftype@figure % give the floats the same precedence
  \let\ftype@table\ftype@figure % give the floats the same precedence
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}[caption=A listing,float]
a=1
\end{lstlisting}

\begin{lstlisting}[caption=Another,float]
b=2
\end{lstlisting}

\begin{figure}
F
\caption{A figure}
\end{figure}

\begin{table}
G
\caption{A table}
\end{table}

\begin{lstlisting}[caption=Again,float]
c=3
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @Rick I made a small change; fix your code too.

Comment: Thanks again. I fixed my code, but I didn't notice what that new line does. Can you give me a brief explanation?

Comment: @Rick Without the added line, there would still be two independent float queues, one for figures and one for listings, so the order could be wrong, with figure 3 before listing 2. The added line adds listings to the queue for figures.

Comment: In my document, lstlisting was numbering per section and figure was numbering continuously. This code numbered figure per section. To get around this, assign the figure counter to lstlisting: "...   `\let\c@lstlisting\c@figure` ... `\let\thelstlisting\thefigure` ... 
  `\let\ftype@figure\ftype@lstlisting` ..."

Comment: @egreg How to share tables' counter with figures and listings?

Comment: @patryk.beza I added the relevant code.

Comment: @patryk.beza: Did you have seen my solution as well? The `table` counter was shared right from the start.

Comment: Yes, I did – thanks for asking. Is any of your solutions preferred in any particular situation?

Comment: @patryk.beza: No, not really. My solution is 'shorter', but needs my `xassoccnt` package

Comment: Why this (`\let\c@lstlisting\c@figure` ... `\let\thelstlisting\thefigure` ... `\let\ftype@figure\ftype@lstlisting`) solution causes ```You can't use `\relax' after \the``` with the latest latex and how this can be corrected in a backward compatible way?

Comment: @Leonid I just updated TeX LIve and get `LaTeX2e <2020-10-01> patch level 1`. The two given codes run flawlessly.

Comment: Here can we change number font to bold?

Comment: @alper `\usepackage{caption}`; read the manual.

Answer (score 1):

A different strategy is to use the `coupled counters` feature from `xassocnt` which establishes a group of counters that are equally stepped if one of the group members is increased. This works for an 'arbitrary' number of counters.

The `\let\ftype@lstlisting\ftype@figure` trick is 'stolen' from egreg's answer -- such features are not contained in `xassoccnt` (yet..., perhaps it will be added one day)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}

\usepackage{xassoccnt}

\DeclareCoupledCountersGroup{figuretablelistings}

% Only needed since listings defines the lstlisting at the begin of the document, not in the preamble 
\makeatletter
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \DeclareCoupledCounters[name=figurelistings]{figure,table,lstlisting}
  \let\ftype@lstlisting\ftype@figure % give the floats the same precedence
}
\makeatother



\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}[caption=A listing,float]
a=1
\end{lstlisting}

\begin{lstlisting}[caption=Another,float]
b=2
\end{lstlisting}

\begin{figure}
F
\caption{A figure}
\end{figure}

\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{ll}
  \hline
  \TeX & \LaTeXe \tabularnewline
  \hline
  ConTeXt & Lua\LaTeX  \tabularnewline
  \hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{A Table}
\end{table}


\begin{lstlisting}[caption=Again,float]
c=3
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

[image]