# How can I remove semicolon after Figure caption and make its number bold, when listing caption changed into Figure

Tags: captions, listings

I have applied in combination of following two solutions. [How to make figure and listing share their counter](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/145547/127048) and [How to change listing caption?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/64845/127048). I was able to combine them and make it work but I just want to remove `:` after the Figure.

The template I am using does not put `:` after the `Figure N` caption. Here is it possible to change the format of caption, where in `Figure 1: Descriptive Caption Text` can where remove the semicolon?

my code:

```tex
\documentclass[AMA,LATO1COL]{WileyNJD-v2} % \documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}% http://ctan.org/pkg/listings
\renewcommand{\lstlistingname}{\textbf{Figure}}% Listing -> Algorithm
\renewcommand{\lstlistlistingname}{List of \lstlistingname s}% List of Listings -> List of Algorithms
\makeatletter
\AtBeginDocument{%
    \let\c@figure\c@lstlisting
    \let\thefigure\thelstlisting
    \let\ftype@lstlisting\ftype@figure % give the floats the same precedence
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=8cm,height=5cm]{myPictureName.png}%
    \caption{My Picture}
\end{figure}

\begin{lstlisting}[caption={Descriptive Caption Text},label=DescriptiveLabel]
    for i:=maxint to 0 do
        ...
    done
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

- class file could be downloaded from here (https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/pb-assets/assets/10991476/AMA-stix_New-1658766862393.zip), under: `ama/WileyNJD-v2.cls`:

or from [overleaf-link](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/a-demonstration-of-the-latex-class-file-for-wiley-njd-journals/bfwqvgnbgcjc).

---

output of the corresponding part:

[image]

In the wanted Figure I want `Figure 2` to be same as templated `Figure N` format I believe it is defined as just bold `\textbf{Figure 2} Descriptive Caption Text`.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The class loads [`caption`](//ctan.org/pkg/caption) which allows you to add

```
\captionsetup[lstlisting]{
  labelfont=bf,
  labelsep=space
}
```

somewhere in the preamble (after loading [`listings`](//ctan.org/pkg/listings)). This provides the formatting you're after (that matches that of the `figure` float/environment).

Here's a complete minimal example:

[image]

```
\documentclass[AMA,LATO1COL]{WileyNJD-v2} % \documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listings}% http://ctan.org/pkg/listings

\renewcommand{\lstlistingname}{\textbf{Figure}}% Listing -> Algorithm
\renewcommand{\lstlistlistingname}{List of \lstlistingname s}% List of Listings -> List of Algorithms
\makeatletter
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \let\c@figure\c@lstlisting
  \let\thefigure\thelstlisting
  \let\ftype@lstlisting\ftype@figure % give the floats the same precedence
}
\makeatother

\captionsetup[lstlisting]{
  labelfont=bf,
  labelsep=space
}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \caption{My Picture}
\end{figure}

\begin{lstlisting}[caption={Descriptive Caption Text},label=DescriptiveLabel]
for i:=maxint to 0 do
  ...
done
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```